# Twilio - How do I set the langauge parameter in xml voice file?

Tags: php, twilio, twilio-api, voice

We have been utilizing the Twilio php library for several years and have recently attempted to have our voice calls from XML files use the a different language.

Our code is building the following xml file for test purposes.

```
<Response>
    <Pause length='1'/><Say voice='alice' language='es-MX'>Prueba de nuevos manejadores de mensajes. ¿Recibiste este mensaje, Timoteo?</Say><Pause length='1'/>
</Response>
```

We have also tried placing a comma after voice-'alice'.

When the voice file plays, the language is not changed from english and so the phrase is not spoken properly.

What must we do to get the language parameter to be accepted?

Comment: Have you tried using double quotes instead of single quotes? The TwiML examples use double quotes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  We found a coding error in the decision logic for setting the spanish parameter.

Answer (score 0):

We found the issue. It was a coding error on our part which was causing the setting of the language to be skipped.